# Defining Foreign and Parent Keys

Tags: sql, oracle, database-design

I have a database project I'm working on for a school project, One of my particular tables is all foreign keys other than one column of the primary key.  When I attempt to `INSERT INTO` any type of value I get the error message:

```
--Insert failed for rows  1  through  50 
--ORA-02291: integrity constraint (112ZACCARO.SYS_C0013505) violated - parent key not found
```

That constraint is for the `Helmet` column. I need to find out how to reference the primary key of `PArmorOptions`.  I did establish all primary keys and foreign keys in the following manner, I wont display the primary key for `PCharacterBuilds` as I do not think it is necessary.

```
ALTER TABLE PCharacterBuilds ADD FOREIGN KEY (ClassName) REFERENCES PClasses(ClassName);
ALTER TABLE PCharacterBuilds ADD FOREIGN KEY (Helmet) REFERENCES PArmorOptions(OptName);
ALTER TABLE PCharacterBuilds ADD FOREIGN KEY (Chestpiece) REFERENCES PArmorOptions(OptName);
ALTER TABLE PCharacterBuilds ADD FOREIGN KEY (Gauntlets) REFERENCES PArmorOptions(OptName);
ALTER TABLE PCharacterBuilds ADD FOREIGN KEY (LegArmor) REFERENCES PArmorOptions(OptName);
ALTER TABLE PCharacterBuilds ADD FOREIGN KEY (Boots) REFERENCES PArmorOptions(OptName);
```

and `PArmorOptions`

```
CREATE TABLE PArmorOptions
(
  OptName NVARCHAR2(50),
  Rarity NVARCHAR2(20),
  ArmorMaterial NVARCHAR2(20)
);

ALTER TABLE PArmorOptions ADD PRIMARY KEY (OptName);
ALTER TABLE PArmorOptions ADD FOREIGN KEY (MaterialID) REFERENCES PArmorType(MaterialID);
```

Comment: The error message says that you are trying to insert a value for the `Helmet` field, which cannot be found as primary key  in `PArmorOptions`.

Comment: Check constraint evaluation time. VERB Time -vs- Commit time?

Comment: @Elyasin yea, I declared the PK with the `alter table` statement above, so I'm not sure why it wont match up

Comment: What I meant is that you are trying to `insert` data in that foreign key field, and that this data does not exist as a primary key value in the referenced table.
@APC answer makes it clear. Yor are, IMO, not respecting his advice.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but the data does exist, I've double and triple checked the tables I am referencing with the foreign keys and it is absolutely there

Answer (score 2):

An INSERT statement for `PCharacterBuilds` table might look something like this:

```
insert into PCharacterBuilds (ClassName,Helmet,Chestpiece,Gauntlets,LegArmor,Boots) 
values ('RANGER', 'MORION', 'CHAINMAIL', 'LEATHER', 'LEATHER', 'HOBNAILED');
```

The purpose of a foreign key is to ensure that records in a child table contain only permitted values. Your primary key on `PArmorOptions` is `OptName`. So for the above statement to work you need five records in `PArmorOptions`, one for each of 'MORION', 'CHAINMAIL', 'LEATHER', 'LEATHER' and 'HOBNAILED'. Similarly you must have a record in `PClasses` where `ClassName` = 'RANGER'.

Note that because these are string keys so the inserted values must match **exactly**: case, spelling, spaces, etc must match. You are getting `ORA-02291` because those necessary records do not exist in the parent table(s). Either the records are not there at all, or the values are different.

Comment: so my actual question is "is there a different way to define the primary key other than how I have done it so that my foreign keys can actually reference the data in the PArmorOptions table"

Comment: That's pretty hard to answer without more details. Please post the structure of the parent details, some sample data and what you're expecting the `PCharacterBuilds` record to look like. Please remember, you know what your code looks like and what you're trying to achieve; we only know **what you tell us**.

Comment: sure I'll post the definition for the `PArmorOptions` Table, and the records in `PCharacterBuilds` is just the names of different items of character builds that i fabricated for the sake of this project.  There are some null values but nothing that is in either of the components of the primary keys